# When retrieving data from AppSync to Elasticsearch, '500:InternalFailure' appears

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-appsync, aws-cdk, aws-elasticsearch

#### Summary

As shown in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-elasticsearch.html), I am using AppSyncResolver for AmazonElasticsearch to retrieve data from Elasticsearch using GraphQL.
It was working fine until yesterday, but when I ran the API today, the ResponseMapping was not returned.
It returns the following error as status.

```
InternalFailure
The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.
HTTP Status Code: 500
```

The problem is happening in three AWS environments (dev/stg/prod) as well.
I haven't changed the configuration or implementation of "AppSync -> ES" in the last month or so.
I would like to solve this problem, but I can't figure out the cause and solution, so please help me.

#### Versions

Elasticsearch: 7.1
aws-cdk/aws-appsync: 1.91.0

#### Error Description

The following error occurs when performing Elasticsearch data acquisition from AppSync.

```
InternalFailure
The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.
HTTP Status Code: 500
```

#### Execution details

The Resolver we are using has the following implementation.

```
private buildPhotoPostsResolver(): appsync.CfnResolver {
    const r = this.newResolver("PhotoPostsResolver", {
        apiId: this.apiId,
        typeName: "Query",
        fieldName: "photoPosts",
        dataSourceName: this.dataSources.elasticsearch.name,
        requestMappingTemplate: `
        #set($where = "")
        #if(! $util.isNullOrEmpty($ctx.args.userId))
            #set($where = "WHERE userId = '" + $ctx.args.userId + "'")
        #elseif(! $util.isNullOrEmpty($ctx.args.hashTag))
            #set($where = "WHERE hashTag = '" + $ctx.args.hashTag + "'")
        #end
        #set($from = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.from, 0))
        #set($size = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.size, 20))
        {
            "version": "2017-02-28",
            "operation": "POST",
            "path": "/_opendistro/_sql",
            "params": {
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": {
                "query": "SELECT * FROM photo_post $where ORDER BY datetime desc LIMIT $size OFFSET $from"
            },
            },
        }`,
        responseMappingTemplate: `
        [
            #foreach($entry in $context.result.hits.hits)
            #if( $velocityCount > 1 ) , #end
            $utils.toJson($entry.get("_source"))
            #end
        ]`,
    });
    r.addDependsOn(this.dataSources.elasticsearch);
    return r;
}
```

#### What we checked.

- The status of the ES was active.
- The ES host specified in the code matches the value you can see in the AWS console.
- The access policy of the ES has not been changed recently.

Please let me know if you have any related information.
Thanks.